# Angular get data from multiple http services and map them

Tags: angular

Hello I've this angular model:

```
import { MetodiPagamento } from './MetodiPagamento';
import { StatiRichieste } from './StatiRichieste';

export class Fatture {
  idFattura: number;
  rifFattura: string;
  customer: string;
  dataFattura: Date;
  invoiceAmount: number;

  idMetodoPagamento: number;
  metodoPagamento?: MetodiPagamento;

  idStatoRichiesta:number;
  statoRichiesta:StatiRichieste;
 
}
```

I can pupulate an array of "Fatture" from http request:

```
getAllFatture(): Observable<Fatture[]> {
    return this.http.get<Fatture[]>(FATTURE_URL).pipe(
      tap((_) => this.handleError.log(`FATTURE SERVICE`,`Recuperate tutte le fatture`)),
      catchError(this.handleError.handleError<Fatture[]>('GET ALL FATTURE')),
    );
  }
```

at this point I need to map each array element with **MetodiPagamento** and **StatiRichieste** each one has it's own service.

I've have a gest-fatture component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IconNamesEnum } from 'ngx-bootstrap-icons';
import { element } from 'protractor';
import { forkJoin, from } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/map';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Fatture } from '../models/Fatture';
import { MetodiPagamento } from '../models/MetodiPagamento';
import { StatiRichieste } from '../models/StatiRichieste';
import { FattureService } from '../services/Fatture.service';
import { MessaggiService } from '../services/Messaggi.service';
import { MetodiPagamentoService } from '../services/metodi-pagamento.service';
import { StatoRichiesteService } from '../services/stato-richieste.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gest-fatture',
  templateUrl: './gest-fatture.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gest-fatture.component.scss'],
})
export class GestFattureComponent implements OnInit {
  fatture: Fatture[] = [];
  fattura: Fatture;
  public IconNames = IconNamesEnum;
  metodiPagamento: MetodiPagamento[] = [];

  constructor(
    private fattServ: FattureService,
    private mess: MessaggiService,
    private metodiService: MetodiPagamentoService,
    private statiRichiestaService: StatoRichiesteService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getFatture();
    this.getMetodiPagamento();
  }

  getFatture(): void {
    this.fattServ.getAllFatture().subscribe((res) => {
      this.fatture = res;
      this.fatture.forEach((ft) => {
        this.statiRichiestaService.getStatoFromFattura(ft).subscribe((st) => {
          ft.statoRichiesta = st[0];
          this.metodiService
            .getMetodoPagamento(ft.idMetodoPagamento)
            .subscribe((mt) => (ft.metodoPagamento = mt[0]));
        });
      });
    });
  }

  getMetodoPagamento(id: number): MetodiPagamento {
    return this.metodiPagamento.find((met) => id === met.idMetodoPagamento);
  }

  getMetodiPagamento(): void {
    this.metodiService
      .getMetodiPagamento()
      .subscribe((resp) => (this.metodiPagamento = resp));
  }

  openRate($event) {
    this.mess.add(
      'Fattura cliccata: ' + $event.currentTarget.firstChild.firstChild.data
    );
  }
}
```

and HTML:

```
<h1>Elenco Fatture</h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Rif. Fattura</th>
      <th scope="col">Customer</th>
      <th scope="col">Data Fattura</th>
      <th scope="col">IMPORTO</th>
      <th scope="col"># Metodo</th>
      <th scope="col">Metodo</th>
      <th scope="col">Stato</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of fatture; index as i">
      <th scope="row">
        <a routerLink="/gest_rate/{{ item.idFattura }}"
          ><i-bs [name]="IconNames.Arrow90degRight"></i-bs
          >{{ item.idFattura }}</a
        >
      </th>
      <td>{{ item.rifFattura }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.customer }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.dataFattura | customDate }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.invoiceAmount | currency: "EUR" }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.idMetodoPagamento | number }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.metodoPagamento.descrizione }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.statoRichiesta.descrizione}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

but I get these kind of errors:
**core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'descrizione' of undefined**

Is there a way to create an array of "Fatture" getting data from all http services?

Thanks

Comment: please console.log(fatture) and add screenshot in the question body.

Comment: my code works, but i wish to know if is there a more elegant solution.